# Сборочная система верхнего уровня для проекта на C++

Tags: c++, cmake, build-automation

Начал писать кроссплатформенный проект на C++ (Windows/Linux, VS/MinGW/GCC/Clang). Помогите определиться с системой сборки верхнего уровня.

На нижнем уровне за непосредственно компиляцию будут отвечать MSBuild (VS) и вариации make (всё остальное). Описание проекта будет в виде cmake. Нужно на чём-то написать сборочные скрипты верхнего уровня, которые будут управлять всеми типовыми операциями с репозиторием:

- Развёртыванием репозитория (раскладка выходных файлов по директориям и т. п.), поиском и анализом окружения (напр., установленных утилит);
- Запуском cmake configure под каждую из используемых конфигураций с установкой всех параметров (директории, флаги и т. д.);
- Запуском cmake --build;
- Запуском тестов;
- Выполнением редких операций вроде инкремента номера версии, перегенерации генерируемого кода и т. п., создание коммитов гита для таких правок;
- Определением правильной последовательности запусков (например, cmake configure нельзя будет сделать сразу для всего дерева, т. к. некоторые проекты являются результатом выполнения других проектов).

Эти скрипты будут локально использоваться разработчиками и запускаться на Jenkins.

Требования к системе:

- Кросс-платформенность (Windows, Linux), чтобы одни и те же скрипты запускались без правок;
- Типовые операции (запуск cmake, запуск тестов, архивация) должны описываться в одном месте и повторно использоваться с разными параметрами (в т. ч. в составе одного запуска по типу "прогнать все тесты под всеми платформами");
- Развитый скриптовый язык, чтобы типовые операции (поиск-замена в файлах и т. п.) можно было делать прямо из сборочных скриптов, не плодя дополнительный уровень;
- Возможность передачи параметров из командной строки и через окружение при запуске (например, добавлять опции компилятора через интерфейс Jenkins для конкретных билдов);
- Встроенная система логирования, например, чтобы лог при запуске батников "сборка и тесты под MinGW" и "сборка и тесты под VS" в один клик вывод перенаправлялся в разные файлы с возможностью продолжать видеть его в консоли;
- Развитая система триггеров пересборки отдельных целей (файл обновился, файл добавился в директорию, в идеале - возможность задавать свои триггеры);
- Возможность распараллеливания длительных однопоточных задач (загрузки, тесты).

Какую систему посоветуете? Скриптовые языки общего назначения (bash, Python, batch) выглядят как оверкилл, слишком многое придётся делать руками, наверняка есть системы, где всё это уже прописано. make слишком платформозависимый. cmake вообще не про это.

Из тех, что понравилось, - NAnt и Pynt. Но первый давно не поддерживается, заточен, в основном, под .Net, имеет диалект (как для задач, так и для выражений) многословный и при этом ограниченный, плюс не умеет в триггеры и параллельное выполнение. У второго многие вещи (логирование, запуск процессов с перенаправлением вывода в консоль и в лог, распараллеливание задач) придётся делать вручную либо допиливать.

Comment: Я извиняюсь, может я чего-то не понял, но почему для этого не использовать все тот же cmake? Что означает "cmake вообще не про то"? Как раз таки cmake умеет делать все из того что вы перечислили, кроме запуска

Comment: ... Кроме запуска самого себя - этого вообще ничто не может. Поиск, копирование, замена, анализ окружения, интеграция с гит, распаралеливание, тесты - это то что он умеет прямо из коробки.

Comment: То, что вы ищите называется "система непрерывной интеграции".

Comment: @Andrej Levkovitch
cmake - это описание проекта, а не движок для запуска отдельных задач. Там не настраивается, куда пойдёт логирование, нет распараллеливания задач или контроля над выполнением внешних процессов (игнорирования кода выхода, например). Задачи типа "собрать то, что уже сконфигурено"/"сконфигурить, собрать, прогнать тесты под конкретную платформу"/"сделать всё под все платформы"/"только очистить" в виде одной простой команды под ним не вызываются. Это не то, что нужно.

Comment: @Chorkov
В CI (Jenkins) эти скрипты будут запускаться, да, но нужна также возможность их запуска на машине программиста без сложной настройки локального окружения.

Comment: @Andrej Levkovitch, или точнее: да, cmake будет применяться, но вызвать cmake один раз для того, чтобы собрать в разных директориях версии проекта под разные платформы (GCC/Clang, VS/MinGW, Debug/Release), разложив аккуратно по директориям, и все их протестировать, невозможно - там платформа и конфигурация зашиваются при запуске. Соответственно, это или последовательность вызовов, или скрипт. Вот этот скрипт я и хочу написать кросс-платформенно и, очевидно, не на cmake.

Comment: @Furax под разные платформы? Ни что из того что вы перечислили не является платформой. Ну а что касается последовательности вызова - а в чем проблема взять любой скриптовый язык и в нем прописать последовательность вызовов cmake, например python, или ВНИМАНИЕ! тот же cmake? Что касается запуска отдельных задач, описанных вами , то cmake, вообщето, имеет команды для: собрать что уже скофигурено, прогнать тесты, очистить. Чтобы сделать же это под все "платформы" нужно сначала понять что вы имеете ввиду под платформами.

Comment: @Andrej Levkovitch
Я писал в самом вопросе, почему не хочу брать скриптовый язык общего назначения - потому что логирование, распараллеливание вызовов, парсинг входных параметров с целью определить, какую именно часть работы нужно сделать при данном запуске (то, что в сборочных системах вроде NAnt, make или Pynt определяется как цель), разруливание зависимостей между целями и т. п. придётся пилить вручную, и это оверкилл. Мне нужен один скрипт, вызов целей откуда делает разные операции над репозиторием как набором проектов, а не над отдельным проектом.

Comment: @Andrej Levkovitch "Платформа" - это компилятор (генератор в терминах cmake) плюс конфигурация (BUILD_TYPE). cmake не может за один запуск сконфигурировать/собрать проект и для VS-Release, и для MinGW-Debug, наример, а это одна из стандартных операций ("собрать и прогнать все тесты под всеми компиляторами и конфигурациями"). Соответственно, cmake будет вызываться много раз, и мне и нужно написать сборочный скрипт, который будет обрабатывать эти множественные вызовы cmake.

Comment: @Andrej Levkovitch Ещё. В cmake нет удобного способа определить отдельные цели, как в make, чтобы потом простой командой типа `cmake run-tests-all-platforms` или `cmake publish-artifacts` запускать последовательность действий. Сравните команды cmake и make и поймёте, о чём я говорю. Распараллеливания действий в cmake нет - нельзя во время закачки файла запустить ещё тесты из двух проектов и конфигурирование третьего. Команды cmake выполняются для конкретных директорий, и раскладку по ним тоже неудобно прописывать - параллельно будут существоать проекты VS и MinGW для одних и тех же исходников.

Comment: @Furax мы точно говорим об одном и том же cmake? Потому что тот cmake что я знаю, умеет определять отдельные цели (есть же флаг --target). Что касается распаралеливания конфигурирования... Вы видимо не понимаете, что cmake при конфигурировании создает дополнительные файлы, которые и используются для компиляции. Так что ваше желание запустить конфигурацию для другого компилятора во время компилирования предыдущей в ТОЙ ЖЕ ДИРЕКТОРИИ - чревата ошибкой. Но никто вам не запрещает сделать это в разных директориях (разместить конфигурационные файлы), а это уж распаралеливайте как хотите.

Comment: @Furax и вообще ваши цели мне не понятны: когда вы говорите что вам нужно выполнить череду действий с cmake и я вам на это предлагаю воспользоваться любым скриптовым языком, то вы начинаете уже говорить о целях для компиляции - будто хотите заменить весь cmake...

Comment: @Andrej Levkovitch `--target` - это проект, который будет собран. Я говорю о целях более высокого уровня, вроде "собрать и протестировать все проекты под все компиляторы", "протестировать конкретный набор проектов под конкретный компилятор", "закачать артефакты в репозиторий" и т. д. Писать отдельный скрипт на каждую такую цель накладно, хочется свести их в систему в стиле make/NAnt/Pynt. Про временные файлы cmake я в курсе, разумеется, проекты будут лежать в разных поддиректориях - я как раз и спрашиваю, чем этот процесс можно "распараллелить как хочу", т. к. средствами cmake это не делается.

Comment: @Andrej Levkovitch И вообще, cmake не умеет логировать свой вывод в файл параллельно с консолью, как NAnt, т. е. уже заранее не подходит под требования - часть операций придётся "прикручивать" снаружи.

Comment: @Furax насчет логирования в файл - почему бы не использовать перенаправление вывода? Что же касается определение "целей более высокого уровня" - а что вам мешает эти цели более высокого уровня определять в cmake? Есть же add_custom_target и add_custom_command. Вот есть у вас cmakelist проекта, а будет cmakelist более высокого уровня, который и запустит конфигурацию, компиляцию, тесты и все что захотите для вашего проекта. И все это будет в терминах cmake

Comment: @Andrej Levkovitch Перенаправление в файл убирает вывод из консоли, что неудобно; кроме того, так нельзя к выводу в файл добавить хотя бы метки времени. Информация о том, в какой файл перенаправлен вывод, будет оторвана от CMakeLists. add_custom_target и add_custom_command удобны, но как минимум, платформозависимы (Linux/Windows), не дают определять кастомные условия пересборки, плюс это не цели вида "выполнить другую цель с такими-то параметрами".

Вообще, как я уже писал, cmake не поддерживает распараллеливание и логирование, так что уже не подходит.

Comment: @Furax в таком случае у вас нет других вариантов, как написать свою систему сборки с блэкджэком и логированием.

Comment: @Andrej Levkovitch Только потому, что не подходит cmake? Ладно вам. Тот же NAnt весьма близок к тому, что мне нужно, наверняка есть что-то ещё более подходящее.